# Trouble passing value from view to controller in Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two model Product and Category, they have has_many, and belongs_to association respectively. Now, what I am trying to do is when I click on particular category I want all the products of that category to be listed. How do I do that

here is my view

```
 <p><%=link_to @product.category.name, show_by_category_products_path(@product.category.id)%> <%= @product.name%> <%=@product.category.id%><p>
```

and method in controller

```
  def show_by_category
   @products = Product.where("category_id=?", :id)
  end
```

Thanks! (I know its simple stuff, but sometimes you get blind and can't see a straightforward way so you have to sought help of others)

EDIT
okay maybe I figured out a way to go around this.. but I am not sure if it is done in right way

Now my view and model looks something like this

```
<p><%=link_to @product.category.name, show_by_category_product_path(id: @product.id)%> <%= @product.name%>

def show_by_category
 @prod = Product.find(params[:id])
 @products = Product.where('category_id=?', @prod.category_id)
end
```

Tell me if this is right way?

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you add a route for your custom action (`show_by_category`)? It should probably be something like `member do; get :show_by_category; end` in your `resources :products do ... end` block.

Comment: yes I have added routes. I don't get array of product. Its nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your find should look more like `Category.find(params[:id]).products`. But try to follow RESTful routing principles, and nest your resources. Rails will do much more for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read at least [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide, because you are doing it wrong.